# Groupby giving keyerror

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, `df`, defined as:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [timestamp, device_type, os]
```

I am trying to groupby timestamp and device type and preform .agg on it such as:

```
df.groupby(['timestamp', 'device_type']).agg({'sessions_sum': 'sum'})
```

This is giving me a KeyError:

```
** KeyError: KeyError('timestamp',)
```

I have read over pandas documentation but I am unsure where I am going wrong. How can I successfully use groupby?

Comment: can you add a data screenshot image here?

Comment: Try groupby(level=0).agg... You groupby by index level instead of name.

Comment: from your data frame definition, it has no columns so that's why it throwing an error,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error is because, `timestamp, device_type, os` are `index` of the df, not actual columns.

So, you can either do a:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.groupby(['timestamp', 'device_type']).agg({'sessions_sum': 'sum'})
```

OR:

```
df.groupby(level=0).agg
```